# Dynamically load images inside jar

Tags: java, image, loading, slick

I'm using Slick2d for a game, and while it runs fine in Eclipse, i'm trying to figure out how to make it work when exported to a runnable .jar. I have it set up to where I load every image located in the res/ directory. Here's the code

```
/**
 * Loads all .png images located in source folders.
 * @throws SlickException
 */
public static void init() throws SlickException {

    loadedImages = new HashMap<>();
    try
    {
        URI uri = new URI(ResourceLoader.getResource("res").toString());
        File[] files = new File(uri).listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
            {
                if(name.endsWith(".png"))
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

        });

        System.out.println("Naming filenames now.");

        for(File f:files)
        {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            Image image = new Image(fis, f.getName(), false);
            loadedImages.put(f.getName(), image);
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException | FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println("UNABLE TO LOAD IMAGES FROM RES FOLDER!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    font = new AngelCodeFont("res/bitmapfont.fnt",Art.get("bitmapfont.png"));

}
```

Now the obvious problem is the line `URI uri = new URI(ResourceLoader.getResource("res").toString());` If I pack the res folder into the .jar there will not be a res folder on the filesystem. How can I iterate through all the images in the compiled .jar itself, or what is a better system to automatically load all images?

Comment: this sounds more like a java question, I would suggest try it under   SO site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem a week ago, and the solution is to use InputStreams. I don't know how ResourceLoader from Slick works, but files are correctly loaded both in filesystem and in JARs using this code:

```
String filepath = "/package1/package2/file.lol";

InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(filepath);
```

and in your code you can do for example:

```
FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) inputStream;
```

If - like in your code - you want to search for files in directories, you have to write different code for the two cases(filesystem and jar):

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource(directoryPath);
File directory = new File(url.getFile());

if (directory.exists()) {
     // we are running this code from filesystem
} else {
     // we are running this code from jar
}
```

You can find my implementation [here](https://github.com/rosickteam/OpenGL/blob/master/rosick/TutorialChooser.java) (line 130).

Comment: Haha, looking at your implementation helped a bunch! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that it helped you :)

Comment: Looks like the link to github is broken.

Answer (score 0):

This one just does not work this way.

You can't list files by directory inside a JAR file. Those files are placed inside the classpath when running the JAR and you need to access every file directly by its name. Access based on the folder structure does not work when accessing files inside the classpath.

You don't "notice" the difference in loading in this case because you are using the ResourceLoader that comes with Slick. In general that is the correct thing to do, but in this case it "hides" the fact that the classpath data is load and not the filesystem data.

So you either need to write down explicit what files you want to load or you need to generate some sort of file list while building the JAR file. Or you need a naming conversation that allows you to load all images. Something like `image0000.png`, `image0001.png`, `image0002.png`, ...

In case you choose to use a filelist you may look at the ANT build system and at fileset, filelist and pathconverter in order to get the automated generation of those lists going.